# Placebo effect in randomized controlled trials (RCTs)

Tags: bias, clinical-trials, random-allocation

How does the number of intervention arms in a given RCT comparing several interventions to a placebo affect the placebo effect?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess there is no specific effect on placebo, excluding the risk of reducing sample size/statistical power, as long as randomization and blinding is properly enforced.